# kontakt beacon is not detecting

Tags: android, beacon, ibeacon-android, android-ibeacon

This is first time i am working with beacon and android, can someone please help what i missed here. I am using beacon eddystone device. 
After startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion it shows 0 device detcted

Dependencies:

-implementation 'org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2+'

Source Code :

```
package com.XXX.yyyy.summa;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.util.Log;

import org.altbeacon.beacon.Beacon;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconConsumer;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconParser;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.Identifier;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.MonitorNotifier;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.Region;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;

import static com.kone.schinnas.summa.MonitoringActivity.TAG;

public class MyActivity extends Activity implements BeaconConsumer, MonitorNotifier {

    private BeaconManager mBeaconManager;

    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mBeaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this.getApplicationContext());
        // Detect the main Eddystone-UID frame:
        mBeaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_UID_LAYOUT));
        mBeaconManager.bind(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
        Region region = new Region("all-beacons-region", null, null, null);
        mBeaconManager.addMonitorNotifier(this);
        try {
            mBeaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(region);
            int i = 0;
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
        Log.d(TAG, "I detected a beacon in the region with namespace id " + region.getId1() +
                " and instance id: " + region.getId2());
    }

    public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
    }

    public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int state, Region region) {
    }


    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mBeaconManager.unbind(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you give location and bluetooth permissions to your app?

Answer (score 0):

Did you give location and bluetooth permissions to your app?

[Getting Location Permission](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/requesting_permission.html)